# res.render() doesn't render right

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I'm making a MERN app for the first time but this res.render() doesn't render right.

```
const express = require('express')
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const MongoClient  = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const connectionString = 'mongodb+srv://abd456:abd123@cluster0.exnpi0k.mongodb.net/expresslearn?retryWrites=true&w=majority'
const app = express()


MongoClient.connect(connectionString, { useUnifiedTopology: true })
.then(client => {

const db = client.db('star-wars-quotes')
const quotesCollection = db.collection('quotes')

app.set('view engine',"ejs")

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended : true }))



app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  
  db.collection('quotes')
    .find()
    .toArray()
    .then(results => {
      console.log(results)
      res.render('index', { quotes: results })
      
    })
    .catch(error=> console.log(error))
});


app.post('/quotes',(req,res)=>{
  quotesCollection  
    .insertOne(req.body)
    .then(result =>{
      res.redirect('/')
    })
    .catch(error=> console.error(err))
})

app.listen(3000,()=>{
    console.log('hola')
})
```

})
.catch(error => console.error(error))

here's the browser result.

" ��<�!DOCTYPE html> <�html lang="en"> <�head> <�meta charset="UTF-8"> <�meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"> <�title>Document<�/title> <�/head> <�body> <�h1>wherever I go there's a shadow of you!<�/h1> <�form action="/quotes" method="post"> <�input type="text" placeholder="name" name="name"> <�input type="text" placeholder="quote" name="quote"> <�button type="submit">submit<�/button> <�/form> <�/body> <�/html> "

I wanted it to render index.ejs but it gives the html code in the browser.

please help

Comment: That is impressively mangled.

Comment: Are you sure that code is running?

Comment: Check the content-type and the character encoding on your generated HTML.  You should be able to easily see that in the browser inspector.  It looks to me like there's some confusion about UTF8.  Also, please show your ejs setup code where you register EJS with Express.

Answer (score 1):

I tried using `touch index.ejs` but it didn't work.

Then ChatGPT gave `echo "" > index.ejs` as a substitute so I used it.

I when I deleted the `echo` method file and open a new file using good old "right click > newfile" pasted the same code and tried it worked fine.

Does anybody know why `echo "" > filename` caused problems?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

You need to also include `ejs-mate` to render ejs templates. Type `npm install ejs-mate` in the terminal and then include it in your app.js file by typing `const ejsMate = require('ejs-mate');` and then you need to configure it for the Express app by typing `app.engine('ejs',ejsMate);` in your app.js file (before `app.set('view engine', 'ejs');` and then it should probably render the ejs template correctly.

Comment: doesn't work. same as before